# WikipediaAPI: How do i find informations about a city

Tags: search, wikipedia, city

I want to send a query to Wikipedia. The Reponse contains some informations about a City, which I asked for.

Some examples:
I would get some informations about Munich:
http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=M%C3%BCnchen&rvprop=content&format=xml
These query send me the desired response.

But there are some other cases in which Wikipedia doesn't know what i mean (if i search "Neustadt" on de.wikipedia.org i become a List of different "Neustadts", because there are Many of them.

But how can I catch the desired articel?...In My Database all the Citys have coordinates,zip-codes and phonecodes. But this I can't search in Wikipeida,or?

//EDIT: I search the URL from the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the wikipedia data is its largely unstructured, you might have better luck looking at something like [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/) which is an effort to pull structured information from wikipedia and make it searchable using  [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL)